# PHP single query Multiple UPDATE effecting AUTO_INCREMENT id instead of order_id

Tags: mysql

Here is my super-simple table layout...

> id | order
>
> 1  | 1
>
> 2  | 2

I've been trying to update the order for both entries with a single query however my query tests seem to keep updating the `auto_increment` id field.

My goal is to make id1 = order 2 and id2 = order1 *in a single query*. What am I doing wrong with my query?

```
UPDATE forms
SET order = CASE id 
WHEN 1 THEN 2 
WHEN 2 THEN 1 
END 
WHERE id IN (1,2);
```

Comment: Your query is working just fine http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb26e

Answer (score 1):

How about doing `JOIN`?

```
UPDATE  Tablename AS a
        INNER JOIN Tablename AS b 
            ON  a.id = 1 AND b.id = 2
SET     a.order = b.order,
        b.order = a.order
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8b3c/1)

Comment: Well my code was technically correct as far as I can tell but I up-voted yours because of your interesting approach.

Comment: your code was correct but you need to know the value of `order`. what if you don't? In my code, all you need is to specify the `ID` in which the you want to exchange the value.